# How do variable variables work in conjunction with ++ operator?

Tags: php, variables

Given an array (ex: `$a = [2,3,3,1,5,2]`), find the first duplicate. In this case that would be the value 3, at index 2.

The second duplicate would be 2 because the index is higher(5).

A solution I found online:

```
function firstDuplicate($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v)
        if ($$v++) return $v;
        return -1;
}
```

How does `$$v++` work?

`$$v` would be equal to $2 at first loop, $3 at second loop and so on.

How does ++ apply to this context?
Thanks!

Later edit: When does $$v++ return true?

Comment: `firstDuplicate([-1, -1])` and boom goes the dynamite. Sentinel values suck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things at play here. The code is written in a quite interesting way, albeit complicated to understand.

### First: [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

As you understood, yes on each interaction `$$v` will translate in variables, respectively `$2, $3, $3, $1, $5, $2`.

PHP is quite flexible (maybe even *too much*) so *it allows** to test `if ($2)` even if `$2` clearly was never instantiated before. It *assumes* `NULL` as its value, so the if check fails to pass.

> * "Notice: Undefined variable: $2" will be thrown in the logs but that doesn't "break" the code nor prevents it's execution.

### Second: [Incrementing/Decrementing operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) (`++`)

It's quite important to understand the difference between pre-increment and post-increment.

```
$a = 0;
$b = 0;

($a++ === 1) // FALSE
(++$b === 1) // TRUE
```

The pre-increment **adds to the variable** and then return it's (new, added) value; While the post-increment **returns the variable's current value** and only then adds to it.

### Combining both

For readability, let's translate this one line

```
if ($$v++) return $v;
```

into

```
if ($$v) {
    return $v;
}
$$v = $$v + 1;
```

as that's what's really happening.

---

Jumping to the second iteration (the first `3` in the array, where `$v = 3`, we'd have:

```
// Right now $3 doesn't exist, so it's value is NULL
if ($3) { // "if (NULL)", so it's FALSE
    return 3;
}
$3 = $3 + 1; // "NULL + 1"
// $3 === 1 at this point
```

> *Why* PHP compiles `NULL + 1` = `1` that's another topic altogether ("too flexible", remember?). Bottomline it assumes `NULL`'s *numeric value* is `0`, so `0 + 1 = 1` is parsed.

Now when it comes to the third iteration (the second `3` in the array, where `$v = 3` again - **but** at this time variable `$3` exists and it's value is `1`)

```
// Right now: $3 === 1
if ($3) { // TRUE
    return 3;
}
$3 = $3 + 1; // This line is never reached, the code has "returned" already
```

So that's it, hope it's somewhat easy to understand. It's a lot of different pieces that must be combined to make sense.

Comment: Thank you, that is a clear explanation. Exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand.

Comment: "*so it doesn't complain when you test if ($2) even if $2 clearly was never instantiated before.*" it'll throw an undefined notice surely?

Comment: Good point @James, I updated the answer. I meant "it won't break the code", but to say "it won't complain" was wrong indeed.

Comment: @mathielo, so would you use this solution (with notices) or go another (a little longer) way, like using a temporary array(made from unique values in $a) to compare with $a and get the difference?

Comment: @user3274898 It's possible to avoid the notices just by checking if the variables exist in the first place: `if (!isset($$v)) $$v = 0;` (one-liner solution following the answer's _style_), so no need to use temporary arrays :)

Answer (score 3):

`$$` is part of "variable variables", a powerful but oh so often misused feature of PHP.

In your case, with `$a = [2,3,3,1,5,2]`

```
function firstDuplicate($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v)
        if ($$v++) return $v;
    return -1;
}
```

`$$v` will be equivalent to the variable `$3` which is undefined.

Then `$3++` will create a variable `$3` with value `0` and the condition for the if statement will be false.

When `$3++` is called again (when the duplicate is found) it will have value of `1`, which makes the `if` statement pass and  `return $v;` will terminate the function by returning the first duplicate (the value of `$v`).

Nota that: `0` is equal to `False` and every non-zero value is considered `True`.